# Evaluation indicator for a notebook

Tags: programming, manipulate, evaluation

I have a GUI with a number of `TabView` and other `Manipulate` controls. Sometimes clicking from one tab view to the other can take a while, and I would like to have a global "Please wait" indicator.

So one way is to implement it for each button or slider, but I would essentially like to have a visual indicator that will show if any cell in my notebook is being evaluated.

Any ideas or suggestions? (Have searched for answers here but I only found those related to progress bars for a specific calculation)

Comment: what OS is your GUI running on?

Comment: Doesn't your notebook window change its title to `Running... <filename>`? Mine does and in addition, also shows a ring around the icon to indicate that it is evaluating something (might be mac only).

Comment: OS X, but it is for a Windows implementation. So yes, I know that the cells are evaluating - you can see it by the double cell bracket, but this is too subtle for the end users, and they need a clear graphical sign that something is happening, or they will keep on clicking on various buttons :-)

Comment: I can't play with it right now, but see if you can do something with `$DynamicEvaluation`. It returns `True` if inside a `Dynamic` and `False` otherwise. A `DockedCell` might be a good place to place an indicator

Comment: Why is there a delay? `TabView`s run everything at the beginning and always treat the dynamic content on all tabs as if visible. Is it just a delay because of front end rendering or you placed some dynamic code dependent on the current selected tab that has to run when it is changed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, let's make a 'busy' animation

```
wait =
 DynamicModule[
    {i = 1, b = Import["http://ims.cartoninjas.net/manifoldtemplate/images/BusyAnimation.gif"]},
    Dynamic@Refresh[b[[i = Mod[i + 1, Length[b], 1]]], 
                    UpdateInterval -> .1, 
                    TrackedSymbols -> {}
    ]
 ]
```

[image]

Now, lets make a radio button bar to control the busy state in this demo:

```
Column[{"Waiting", RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[waiting], {True, False}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, here's the `TabView`. I use `Overlay` to overlay the busy animation in the busy state *and* prevent selection of the `TabView`:

```
g = {"Beethoven", "CastleWall", "Cone", "Cow"};
Overlay[
  {
    TabView[(# -> ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", #}] &) /@ g], 
    Dynamic@If[waiting, wait, "", ""]
  }, 
  {1, 2}, 
  Dynamic[If[waiting, 0, 1, 1]], 
  Alignment -> Top
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is the responsibility of your code to set and unset the busy state. Probably somewhere in the beginning and end, respectively, of a `Dynamic` piece of code in `TabView`.

---

**Update** As of Version 10.0.2 `Animator` can be used to create the `busy` animation. There are several kinds available, but one resembling the above can be generated using:

```
Animator[Appearance -> "Necklace"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Any ideas on how to set this busy state ? What function can I use to tell if a notebook is currently evaluating or not?

Comment: @LaraJordan Setting the busy state is simply a question of setting the `waiting` variable to either True or False. If you have a block of code that may be evaluating you could do that at the beginning and end of that block. In the example above I used ExampleData to stand for the code, but it could be a comple program.

Comment: Sorry, I was bieng an idiot! Thanks.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, how about something practical and geared to the notebook structure: ie a set of icons (eg squares or circles) one for each cell in a notebook that progressively go from empty to filled as each cell expression is executed?