# How to show system busy during Dynamic with SynchronousUpdating -> False?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, scheduling

For long running evaluations in `Dynamic` it is recommended that `SynchronousUpdating -> False` be used to prevent time-out. However, when this is used a `DynamicModule` custom interface does not show that it is busy by not allowing user interaction.  The user, having no sign that something is evaluating after they click, can continuously click on an evaluate button and inadvertently queue up many expensive calculations.

Thus my question: How to show that the system is busy while evaluating `Dynamic` with `SynchronousUpdating -> False`?

I thought of two approaches:

1. Set the cursor to busy.
2. Disable the evaluate button during evaluation.

I tried `MouseApperance` and `CurrentValue` for option 1 but did not get very far. My example is below but it gives the `"NoOp"` cursor at all times.  I'm not certain how to proceed with option 2 given my results with option 1.

```
DynamicModule[{pl, tbl, n = 1},
 Dynamic[Refresh[
   Pause[7];
   pl = Plot[Sin[n w] + n, {w, -5, 5}];
   tbl = TableForm[{{n, Sin[n x] + n}}, 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "f[n]"}}];
   (*Dynamic@MouseAppearance[*)
   Column[{
     Button["Update", n = n + 1, ImageSize -> Large, 
      Method -> "Queued"],
     Dynamic@pl,
     Dynamic@tbl
     }]
   (*,
   If[CurrentValue["SynchronousEvaluation"]\[Equal]True,"NoOp",
   "Arrow"]]*)
   ,
   TrackedSymbols -> {n}
   ], SynchronousUpdating -> False]
 ,
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

Uncomment the `Dynamic@MouseAppearance` and the `If` to see my attempt at this.

The actual module is large with many calculations, plots, and tables produced. The `Pause` is set at 7 seconds as the timeout is at 5 seconds. Also, in the module the evaluation time will vary depending on the parameters selected.

I am seeking a solution that allows selection of the text/numbers in tables/grids for copy and paste.  Also, tooltips from plots/charts should continue to work when not evaluating.

Comment: closely related: [Palette button with progress bar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on Kuba's deleted answer. I agree with his observation that "clearer [the] code the easier to fix". So here is Kuba's code made clearer.

```
DynamicModule[{pl, tbl, n = 1, x = 45 °, calculation = False, procedure}, 
  Dynamic[MouseAppearance[
    Column[{
      If[calculation, 
        ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Percolate"], 
        Button["Update", 
          calculation = True; FinishDynamic[];procedure[]; calculation = False;,
          ImageSize -> Large, Method -> "Queued"]],
      If[ValueQ @ pl, pl, ""],
      If[ValueQ @ tbl, tbl, ""]}],
    If[calculation, "NoOp", "Arrow"]], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {calculation}],
  Initialization :>
    (procedure[] := 
      (Pause[5];
       pl = Plot[Sin[n w] + n, {w, -5, 5}];
       tbl =
         TableForm[{{n, x, Sin[n x] + n}}, 
           TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "x", "f[n]"}}];))]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for this.  Also, I realised that you can remove all of the display `If`s by calling the `procedure` function in `Initialization` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some relevant stack exchange posts:

[Showing "updating..." message while Manipulate is re-evaluating](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59286/showing-updating-message-while-manipulate-is-re-evaluating)

[Show Progressbar after pressing a button](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52260/show-progressbar-after-pressing-a-button)

[Evaluation indicator for a notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10302/evaluation-indicator-for-a-notebook)

Igor

Comment: These were useful.